# laravel 5.6 with MySql gives Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException error

Tags: mysql, laravel

There are similar questions under this topic, but none of them gave me an answer. I'm a beginner to laravel and trying to learn by myself. 
When I try to connect *laravel (version 5.6)* with *MySql* it gives this error.

These are the code lines that working with.

**CameraController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Camera;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CameraController extends Controller{

public function postCamera(Request $request){

    $camera = new Camera();

    $camera->email = $request->input('email');
    $camera->password = $request->input('password');

    $camera->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message'=>$camera
    ]);
 }


}
```

**CreateCamreasTable.php**

```
public function up(){

    Schema::create('cameras', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('email');
        $table->text('password');
    });
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('/addCamera', ['as' => 'Camera', 'uses' => 'CameraController@postCamera']);
```

**user.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
       'email',
   ];

    protected $hidden = [
       'password',
   ];
}
```

I couldn't found out what's wrong with my code..

PS- I'm trying with postman app that supports with sending requests and reading responses. what I'm sending is a json object

```
{
    "email" : "rr@gmal.com",
    "password" : "fjf"
}
```

The error that I receive is

[image]

Comment: Add your blade file code (relevant areas only) please.

Comment: what kind of error laravel shown to you? show the error stack trace

Comment: "Method not allowed" means the form method; ie POST or GET. You've specified this as a POST, so I guess you're actually sending a GET request, which is why it's throwing the exception. Try changing your form to a POST.

Comment: How do you get the error? Magic?

Comment: check your form's action is `POST`

Comment: I have not create any .blade code. @Option.

Comment: The errors are added to the code. and i didn't make any form or form actions.

Comment: How are you viewing the form to input then? Using postman?

Comment: POST to `/addCamera` or `/api/addCamera`?

Comment: yes. in postman gives that features

Comment: even it is /addCamera it works as /api/addCamera I think. ( I  tried. :D )

Comment: you should note that route in api.php, all route are prefixed with `/api`

Comment: it is defined clearly in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`